# using MySQL cache query with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, caching

I am using codeigniter with MySQL.

One of my database is a price_table that is quite constant and gets "SELECT" quite often, the access where through the same model_function, so the query would be exactly the same. I think this should be a good example to implement MySQL cached query to improve performance.

I want to use codeigniter function to interact with database as much as possible, so I have codes like:

```
$q = $this->db->select('service_info.*, service_pricing.price, service_pricing.price_ID')
                    ->from('service_pricing')
                    ->where('status','active')
                    ->join('service_info','service_info.service_ID = service_pricing.service_ID ')
                    ->get();
if ($q->num_rows > 0) {
    return $q->result_array();
} else {return FALSE;}
```

I read about the [Database Caching Class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/caching.html) from codeigniter document, but I do not think this is what I want.
The cache described here seems like a global one. In my case, I want it to be a few queries about a relatively constant database.

I am thinking something like [this example](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-in-select.html):

```
SELECT SQL_CACHE id, name FROM customer;
```

Is there a good way I can do it in codeigniter?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried my answer? It must work

Answer (score 1):

You may set cache either global or specific to particular query. If you want to set cache to a query then use like following

```
$this->db->cache_on();
//your number 1 query here. this query will cache


 $this->db->cache_off();
 // number 2 query here. This query will not cached
```

hope clear now